# how to hide featured image in wordpress PAGE

Tags: wordpress

**How to hide Featured image in Wordpress Page,** if i have use Function for Post First image as Featured Image.

**i have use this function--**

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can use is_single() function. execute action hooks inside `if(is_single())`

Comment: hi sir it not works

Comment: can you share me the code you actually added so i can fix it for you.

Comment: hi sir
i have use this https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-automatically-set-post-featured-image

Comment: yes but can you share code where you added the is_single() condition?